# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON"

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've recently picked up a project I was working on a bit ago, and when doing an ajax request, after it submits, it should return a success message or an error message. The code I'm using is the same code I'm using on the rest of my application, and it is working fine without any issues.

I've had the issue for the past 7 or so hours, and I have had no luck fixing it myself, hence why I'm coming here.

PHP Code:

```
if (access) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  dbquery('UPDATE settings SET name="' . escapestring($name) . '"');
  $error['msg'] = "";
  echo json_encode($error);
  exit();
} else {
  $error['msg'] = "You don't have permission.";
  echo json_encode($error);
  exit();
}
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#updateName').ajaxForm(function (error) {
        error = JSON.parse(error);
        if (error['msg'] === "") {
            toastr.success('Name Updated', 'System:', {timeOut: 10000})
        } else {
            toastr.error(error['msg'], 'System:', {timeOut: 10000})
        }
    });
});
```

This code (the returning either success message or error message) seemingly works fine throughout the rest of my application, yet today I haven't been able to get it working no matter what I try.

Edit-
After using console.log(error); , it appears it's not defined. The issue is that this code works fine on other parts of my application

log-

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: error is not defined ReferenceError: error is not defined
```

Comment: What about `if (access) {`? Do you have a constant named `access` or are you missing `$` before that variable?

Comment: @AlonEitan That is a define in another file. The PHP part works without a problem, the issue is returning the JSON.parse but I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: I don't think you need to `error = JSON.parse(error);`, just use the parameter itself without this line

Comment: @AlonEitan - You do need it afaik, because if you don't use it, it returns the 'toastr.error' without any message at all.

Comment: Still no luck after trying what Alon suggested in different forms. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very hard to tell. You need to `console.log(error)` because you're trying to parse it in order to see what value is coming back from the server. Please include the output in the question

Comment: @AlonEitan updated.

Comment: Are you using jQuery ver. that precedes v1.7.2 maybe? Also there is a bug about compatibility issues with [jquery v3](https://github.com/jquery-form/form/issues/544). Last thing - Open the developer tools, check the network tab, and check what the server responded when you made the request. 
Sorry - I'm out of ideas, it looks like this library was not updated over a year, perhaps it's time to move on the something better

Comment: @AlonEitan - Thank you for your help. It was fixed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,  `error = JSON.parse(error);`
The `error` your trying to access is not defined. it shoudl be `var error  = JSON.parse(error);` that is why youre getting an error or undefined variable `error`.

But the JSON error

> “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON”

is different. Can you please make a fiddle and post ur code!

Comment: My mistake, it was now fixed. Thank you!